# C# Generic Partial Classes, interfaces, AND inheritance, all in the same question! (oh my!)

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I've been working on a code generater for my projects and, while all has worked well. But now, I've stumbled upon a detail that I'm not sure how to resolve. This is for my DAL layer, which is intended to allow implementations for diferente dataSources.

so I've got an interface:

```
public interface IUsersDALBase
{
    //defined methods
}
```

a generic class that implements it:

```
public class UsersDALBase<T> : DBDataAccessBase where T : DBDataAccessBase, IUsersDALBase, new()
{   
    protected T _UsersInstance = default(T);

    public string connectionString
    {
        get { return _UsersInstance.connectionString; }
        set { _UsersInstance.connectionString = value; }
    }

    //constructors (...)

    //interface method implementations, that call _UsersInstance methods    (...)
}
```

For reference, DBDataAccessBase just holds the connection string and has disposing methods to standardize the *DALBAse classes. There is also an empty derived definition to extended (and there for not needing the "Base" suffix):

```
 public partial class UsersDAL<T> : UsersDALBase<T>  where T : DBDataAccessBase, IUsersDALBase, new()
{
    //empty in generated file
}
```

this class is just a wrapper around UsersDALBase and is the one I want to extend in a new file. T type classes are mainly autogenerated also, but with DB specific implementations.

So finally, I want to extend UsersDAL in another file with custom methods that the generated code doesn't, and represented by a new interface

```
public interface IUsers2
{
   UsersList GetAppRoleUsers(int NS_AppRole);
}
```

I'm trying something like:

```
public partial class UsersDAL<T> : UsersDALBase<T> where T : DBDataAccessBase, IUsers2, new()
{
    //interface method implementation

    //compile error: Partial declarations of 'DAL.UsersDAL<T>' have inconsistent 
    //constraints for type parameter 'T' -supose i can't have diferente interface 
    //implementations for T...  

}
```

I basicly want UserDAL to have all the autogenerated methods (that implement IUsersDALBAse) and the methods that I've defined in the new interface IUsers2. Any Ideas on how I can get this???

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If multiple files specify type constraints, those constraints have to match I'm afraid.

From section 10.2.3 of the C# 3 spec:

> When a partial generic type
>   declaration includes constraints
>   (where clauses), the constraints must
>   agree with all other parts that
>   include constraints. Specifically,
>   each part that includes constraints
>   must have constraints for the same set
>   of type parameters, and for each type
>   parameter the sets of primary,
>   secondary, and constructor constraints
>   must be equivalent. Two sets of
>   constraints are equivalent if they
>   contain the same members. If no part
>   of a partial generic type specifies
>   type parameter constraints, the type
>   parameters are considered
>   unconstrained.

Could you supply any extra interfaces you want in the partial class declaration as input to the code generator?

Comment: currently, no, But I guess I should include it in the next iteration. My work around for this now is just to implement a specific set of classes for the new interface. Kind of like a single responsability implementation.

Thanks for the clarification.